# how to extract the html content inside cell from google spreadsheet

Tags: html, google-sheets, extract

I have a spreadsheet, where I want to copy the exact HTML format inside of the Spreadsheet cell in HTML

please help

Example:
 url:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rMawPjCOn8C_FGnMfAu0QT2zoJqCqjCuAh-Y52_uwkc/edit#gid=0

Here in the above spreadsheet in column 3, there is a job description

the Exact HTML code inside that Cell is

Required Skills: 
7+ years of Business analyst experience in Risk/Compliance/Basel projects in Credit Risk. (Basel and Credit Experience are must)
Very Good in SQL and PL/SQL
Experience in Banking Domain and Banking Products. 
Preferable experience in Regulatory areas. 
Excellent Verbal and Written communication skills--%>

how can I get this?

Comment: Sure thing moonpie - what have _you_ tried?

Comment: Could you add in your question an example of HTML content you would like to get?

Comment: @Mathemats, the question is simple and what he needs is something like Required Skills:<br/>7+ years of Business .... I google this and this is the first thing that pops out. do you know a function that does this?